# How does the next() function in Express call the next middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I don't want to know how to use the `next()` function, but how does it actually calls the next middleware or the next route. I couldn't find any good resource where I can actually see the code, so if anyone knows where I can find the resource to read will also be helpful.

Comment: The code is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/69a4cf2819c4449ec6ea45649691fb43a528d5d1/lib/router/index.js#L177).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express.js framework is based on **middlewares**.

> An Express application is essentially a series of middleware function calls.

Example:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/user/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('USER');
});
```

In this example, `(req, res, next) => { ... }` is a middleware itself. The `app.get()` method (just like `post`, `put` or any other), always accepts a route paramter (in this example, "/user/:id"), and a number of middlewares (functions with three params: `req`, `res`, `next`).

When using middlewares, you can both send a response back to the client (with `res.send()`) or call the next middleware (with the `next()` function).

Another example

```js
app.get('/user/:id', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Request URL:', req.originalUrl);
  next();
}, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Request Type:', req.method);
  next();
}, (req, res) => {
  console.log('Sending response back');
  res.send(req.params.id); // example
});
```

You can find more info here: [express middleware official guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)